# CodeIgniter - Checking user entered email once completed typing, to confirm if taken or not

Tags: php, codeigniter

Trying to perfect an email form input, where the user can enter their email that is to be associated to their account. However ideally, the system would reject/accept the entered email once they have finished typing (not on form submission). I am using CodeIgniter, and still learning alot unfortunately.

My VIEW/form has the following input:-

```
<?=form_input(array(    
        'name'      =>  'pi_email',
        'id'        =>  'pi_email',
        'value'     =>  isset($email)?$email:'',
        'maxlength' =>  '50',
        'required'  =>  'yes',
        'size'      =>  '50',
        'placeholder' => 'johndoe@example.com',
        'class'     =>  'lg-textbox'
    ));?>
```

On the controller/profile, I have the below as a test to try and catch these inputs and echo if taken or not, right now option 1 is always displayed as "email already taken", when they are not actually. I have seen the below form_validation online, however I do not generally understand the context in which it is to be used successfully

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules($new_email, 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[tbl_users.email]');
        if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
            echo "email already taken";
        } else {
            echo "Valid email!";
        }
```

How could i implement real time check that will display on screen? I know how to use db model to run a query and return results, if = 0 valid, if > 0 then email taken? can this be implemented on the view or has to be done in the controller and then return user to the profile page and display an error message?

Any assistance, general pointing in the right direction would be great

Comment: are you issuing email accounts for your domain? If not, why do you care if an email is "taken"?

Comment: if it is for account verification, a hacker would say: "*thanks a lot for the info, now I know this email exists, now I only need to find a password*". Anyway, what you describe what you want to do can be achieved via AJAX calls (detecting a key-up event and sending a request to the server). I also would rather look into existing AUTH systems and adapt them to my needs, rather than write my own...

Comment: Hi guys, any website with user creations will identify when an email is taken? the purpose is they create an application, then set their email & password to 'save' and return to the app at a later date should they wish too. I will check out AJAX though, thank you!